# MS Office Powerpoint - Embedding video but not as a link

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I know it is possible to link a video, either from local drive or from Youtube. But I am looking to embed the video so I can save it and email it as a .ppt file. Is this possible?

I want to be able to send a powerpoint via email and have users be able to view a video.

If it is not possible, would sending a compressed folder with the video inside there keep the link working so it can be viewed on another PC?

Comment: When you embed a video using the "Insert Video" it should embed the video within the PowerPoint file by default...

Comment: I have been trying that, but the file size of the powerpoint stays the same, and I moved the power point to another PC, and it says it is unable to locate the video.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate your issue. The video I embedded using the `Insert` tab, then selecting `video` from the `media` menu saved the video as part of the file. How are you inserting the video?

Comment: Also, have you looked at the `Save & Send` options in in the `File` tab?

Comment: Insert ->  Video -> Video from file then broswing to it. The video it 200mb.

Comment: Even compressed, not sure a 200MB video is going to email very well. Supposedly, there is no file size limit to PowerPoint, but I am not sure the video size isn't the issue with it embedding properly. Try a small video to see if it will embed correctly.

Comment: I added a much smaller video, still no luck.

Comment: So I found something pretty close. It is called "package presentation for cd". This make a folder with the video and ppt and changes the links to work from that folder.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. The file needs to be a `.pptx`.